# Can "double-dots" be part of the path part of an URL

Tags: http

Is it valid and safe to use the parent directory double-dots inside an URL like in the following example:

`http://example.com/path/../to/file.jpg`

Comment: Why would you do that ?

Comment: Because you can get an URL by combine the base URL of a document with a relative path. e.g. `var url = base_url + relative_path`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) defines URIs.

It describes how paths are hierarchical, and how...

> The path segments "." and "..", also known as dot-segments

... work in a similar way to filesystem paths.

It also describes rules for "relative resolution" in which `.` and `..` may be removed.

Essentially, it is legal and does what you expect.

Comment: You are right, how to remove dot segments is part of the standard. Section [5.2.4 Remove Dot Segments](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-5.2.4) describes it exactly. So I can use this kind of „weird looking“ URL in my scripts. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it absolutely works.
 Just notice that the URL will change so the dots won't be displayed inside it. Like if you do `http://path/to/new/../file` the displayed URL will be `http://path/to/file`