# Javascript picture quiz Images failing to load resource 404 error

Tags: javascript, html, image, bootstrap-5

I am building a simple javascript picture quiz for a project. I have only written the function for show question and possible answers but for some reason when i call the quiz the images aren't loading and i am getting an error re failing to load the resource. The img files work perfectly fine otherwise and i have tried both .png & .jpg and both display the same error.

I have a few elements to add in to the JS like checkAnswer and Display score but i need the images to work as they are the answer buttons.

Corresponding HTML

```
<section id="quiz">
      <div id="quiz-question-card" class="container welcome-card shadow-lg text-dark mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3 class="question-title">Question</h3>
          <p id="question-text"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div id="answer-btns" class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-4">
          
        </div>
      </div>
```

Javascript two sample questions and answers & function;

```
let spQuiz = [
    {
        question: "What planet is closest to the Sun?",
        answers: [
            "../img/venus.png",
            "../img/mercury.png",
            "../img/mars.png",
            "../img/earth.png"
        ],
        correctAnswer: '1'
    },
    {
        question: "Which planet has the highest mountain in our solar system, a volcano named Olympus Mons?",
        answers: [
            "../img/mars.png",
            "../img/jupiter.png",
            "../img/neptune.png",
            "../img/earth.png"
        ],
        correctAnswer: '0'
    },
];

let newQuestion = 0;
function displayQuestion () {
    let question = spQuiz[newQuestion];
    document.getElementById("question-text").innerHTML = question.question;
    let answers = question.answers;
    for (let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        let answer = answers[i];
        let img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = answers;
        img.onclick = function() {
            checkAnswer(i);
        };
        document.getElementById("answer-btns").appendChild(img);
    } 
}

displayQuestion();
```

Comment: I see one mistake: `img.src = answers;` should be `img.src = answer;`, but if that will solve everthing, I cannot tell.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that, i have changed it and still no luck. I have even tried external image links and nothing will load. When executing the quiz i am now getting an accumulation of img thumbnails like the first answer sets have not cleared.

Comment: I don't think that ".." in the path is going to work for security reasons.  Try putting the images somewhere where you can access them without ".." in the path.

Comment: Related question: [Can "double-dots" be part of the path part of an URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43897438/can-double-dots-be-part-of-the-path-part-of-an-url)  And perhaps surprisingly, the answer is yes.